# rails_admin.git installation problem or more general problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

i want to install this https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin
so i pasting those  2 in the gemfile

```
gem 'devise' # Devise must be required before RailsAdmin

gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
```

however when i bundle install, the second one alone seems to give this problem:

```
Fetching git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git
sh: git: command not found
An error has occurred in git when running `git clone "git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git" "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/cache/bundler/git/rails_admin-76c2c78f1892a43807d922e810aef4edcddc12b7" --bare --no-hardlinks`. Cannot complete bundling.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear as if you have git installed. Please follow the [GitHub guide](http://help.github.com/git-installation-redirect) for installing it on your operating system.